# How to call a change a state in a component using a button function from another component In React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, components, state

Long story short; I have a button that involves a function and in that function I want to change the state (in this case a number) from another component that's taking the property from somewhere else.

So to me I made a stats component that takes in the value that I want to change and then the value is coming from the Table component and I want the button that I made that is coming from the Actions
component to change the state from the stats component. So instead of having the button in the Table Component (As seen below) I want to be able to run it from my Actions Component

Attached is the code that kinda works the way I want it but it doesn't look the way I want it (I want to invokve the change state function from the Actions column rather than inside the component where the state lives)

```
const Button = ({ handleClick, action, btnType }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button class={btnType} onClick={handleClick}>
        {action}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Actions = ({ text, value, handleClick }) => {
  return (
    <td>
      <button
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-primary"
        data-toggle="modal"
        id="exampleModal"
      >
        Launch demo modal
      </button>
      <Button btnType="btn btn-secondary" action="Attack" />{" "}
      <Button btnType="btn btn-success" action="Travel" />{" "}
    </td>
  );
};

const Stats = ({ cash }) => {
  return (
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li>
          {" "}
          <span class="green">Cash: </span>
          {cash}
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="red">HP: </span>100
        </li>
        <li>
          <span class="blue">Energy: </span>100
        </li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  );
};

const Table = () => {
  const [cash, setCash] = useState(300);
  const sellAction = ({}) => {
    setCash(cash - 1);
  };
  return (
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Drugs</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Inventory</th>
        <th>Stats</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
      </tr>
      <TableItem />
      <QuantItem />
      <Inventory />
      <Button
        btnType="btn btn-danger"
        handleClick={sellAction}
        action="Sell"
      />{" "}
      <Stats cash={cash} />
      <Actions />
    </table>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass `setCash` or `sellAction` function to `Actions` component as a prop. And then from `Actions` component, pass it to the `Button` component as a prop. Similar to what you did for `cash`.